# Problems interpreting random effects

Tags: regression, mixed-model, random-variable, interpretation, binomial-distribution

I am running a generalised mixed effect model with a binomial response for my thesis.
The model estimated the chance an a subject in a certain group is a female. My final goals is to compare the groups by doing pairwise comparisons between the estimated marginal means.
I use hunting season as a random effect since I assume the population structure differs over the seasons. Based on contingency tables, there is a relationship between sex structure (and age structure) and hunting season. If I add hunting seasons as a fixed effect, it also plays a significant role.

However if I run my model, it seems that the Random effect doesn't play a very big role, which sounds contra intuitive for me.

Code:

```
e = glmer(Sexb ~ `Age class` + group_d + `Age class`:group_d + (1| `Hunting season`),
          data = modeldata, 
          family = binomial,
          control=glmerControl(optimizer = "bobyqa")
          )
summary(e)
```

Output:

```
Show in New Window
Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood (Laplace Approximation) ['glmerMod']
 Family: binomial  ( logit )
Formula: Sexb ~ `Age class` + group_d + `Age class`:group_d + (1 | `Hunting season`)
   Data: modeldata
Control: glmerControl(optimizer = "bobyqa")

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
  2616.8   2689.3  -1295.4   2590.8     1944 

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-4.9410 -0.8933 -0.6638  1.0896  1.5446 

Random effects:
 Groups         Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 Hunting season (Intercept) 0.01505  0.1227  
Number of obs: 1957, groups:  Hunting season, 6

Fixed effects:
                                 Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)  
(Intercept)                        0.3214     0.2589   1.241   0.2146  
`Age class`1                      -0.9958     0.9021  -1.104   0.2697  
`Age class`2                       0.2525     0.6777   0.373   0.7095  
`Age class`3+                      1.0863     0.5227   2.078   0.0377 *
group_dFamily Pack                -0.3705     0.3095  -1.197   0.2313  
group_dSolo                       -0.6988     0.2881  -2.425   0.0153 *
`Age class`1:group_dFamily Pack   14.6728    39.8115   0.369   0.7125  
`Age class`2:group_dFamily Pack  -13.7172    26.3269  -0.521   0.6023  
`Age class`3+:group_dFamily Pack   2.2253     1.1592   1.920   0.0549 .
`Age class`1:group_dSolo           1.2148     0.9164   1.326   0.1850  
`Age class`2:group_dSolo          -0.6274     0.7002  -0.896   0.3703  
`Age class`3+:group_dSolo         -0.8991     0.5481  -1.640   0.1009  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Following https://data.library.virginia.edu/getting-started-with-binomial-generalized-linear-mixed-models/ I perform following steps to interpret my random effect:

Extract the estimated standard deviation:

```
VarCorr(e)

output:

 Groups         Name        Std.Dev.
 Hunting season (Intercept) 0.1227
```

As far as I understand this 0.12 is an estimate of the 0.015.

If a calculate confidence intervals I get the following:

```
 2.5 %    97.5 %
sd_(Intercept)|Hunting season     0 0.3211868
```

0 is part of the confidence interval, suggesting that their may not be random variability between subjects (caused by differences in hunting season?). Which turns out to be contra intuitve for me, however, using normal generalised models would make life much more easier :)

Comment: You can test for the "significance" of the random effects with anova. See this [section of GLMM FAQ](https://tinyurl.com/ymtpa8kj). Note that the advice is to *not* do the test in order to drop the random effects, esp. since your domain knowledge tells you they exist. The tutorial you cite has similar advice: "So in real life we wouldn’t seriously entertain dropping the random effect." The danger is that if there is are (small) random effect sand you ignore them, this would inflate the statistics of the fixed effects.

Comment: PS: The statement "this 0.12 is an estimate of the 0.015." is not correct: 0.12 (the standard deviation) is the square root of 0.015 (the variance)

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this issue!